# Setting up L2TP/IPSec VPN Server with OpenSwan fails during IPSec authentication

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, openswan

I'm trying to set up my Linode server (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) to act as a L2TP/IPSec VPN server for when I'm traveling in China so that I can access Facebook/Twitter/YouTube on the go.

I've followed [m](http://www.elastichosts.com/support/tutorials/linux-l2tpipsec-vpn-server/)[a](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/IPsec_L2TP_VPN_server)[n](http://www.cryptocracy.com/blog/2012/05/13/ipsec-slash-l2tp-vpn-server-with-ubuntu-precise)[y](http://www.slsmk.com/setup-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu/) tutorials on setting it up, but every time I get to checking the `auth.log` nothing comes though, and I just get the error that `The VPN server did not respond`.

I have checked my `iptables`, and `ipsec verify` comes through with everything `[OK]`.

Could someone try and give me a command by command install for this? This is what I have been doing so far:

---

```
$ sudo aptitude install openswan
// Use an X.509 certificate for this host? No
// Old runlevel management superseded

$ sudo nano /etc/ipsec.conf
// Deleted all, inserted this
version 2.0
config setup
    nat_traversal=yes
    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
    oe=off
    protostack=netkey

conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
    rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
    also=L2TP-PSK-noNAT

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    auto=add
    keyingtries=3
    rekey=no
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    type=transport
    left=[MY SERVER'S PUBLIC IP]
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    right=%any
    rightprotoport=17/%any

$ sudo nano /etc/ipsec.secrets
// Deleted all, inserted this
[MY SERVER'S PUBLIC IP] %any: PSK "psk"

$ nano adjust-redirects
// Inserted this
for each in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*
do
    sudo echo 0 > $each/accept_redirects
    sudo echo 0 > $each/send_redirects
done

$ sudo bash adjust-redirects

$ sudo ipsec verify
// All OK except for Opportunistic Encryption Support which is disabled

$ sudo /etc/init.d/ipsec restart
// At this point I tried to connect while monitoring the log, nothing happened and I got the 'Server did not respond' error above.
```

Comment: No answers yet?